# An old game with skeletons and other creatures

Tags: identify-this-game

What old game is this? I don't know when it was released but, I think it was released after 1990 (Not 3D). It is a Platformer. I believe it is about aliens.

In the first level you arrive in a car and there are these skeletons and you shoot them. As you keep on walking there are buildings (or lifts) that you can use. There are collectible crystal shards. After some levels you will find a big skeleton monster in a room. Another level I remember has you on the top of a building and something/someone is firing rockets at you.

There was skeletons in most of the levels and they looked alien. I doubt the name of the game started with B- . Even though it was 90's game I played it on Windows XP . It is most probably a DOS game. It is similar to [Dangerous Dave 2](https://www.google.com/search?kgmid=/m/03wdsl5&hl=en-IN&q=Dangerous+Dave+in+the+Haunted+Mansion&kgs=68953083b82ed580&shndl=0&source=sh/x/kp&entrypoint=sh/x/kp)

Comment: I was wrong there is only one skeleton and it was the giant skeleton itself

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found it! It is [Bio Menance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bio_Menace) released in 1993. I thought for a long time and remembered that the name of the file was "bm". I googled for bm dos game and got it

Comment: Remade recently, available on Steam IIRC

Comment: I can't speak as to Steam, but right now it's _free_ on GoG: https://www.gog.com/game/bio_menace

Comment: Would never have guessed Bio Menace from your description, glad you found it though!